# Is this a good way of handling jQuery Mobile/PhoneGap page change events?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, initialization, jquery-events

I have this script in the `head` of my index.html. I want different scripts to run when different pages are shown, because I populate the pages programatically. Pages have IDs `page1`, `page2` etc. Page-specific functions are called `page1init()`, `page2init()` etc.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
    $("div[data-role=page]").on('pageshow', function(){
        eval(this.id + 'init()')
    })

    $('#page1').trigger('pageshow')
})
```

Is this reasonable and does using `eval()` here introduce security issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has answered, I suppose I have to default to a 'yes'? Please feel free to edit this/answer if you feel otherwise.